# Angular 2+ Dynamic HTML template

Tags: javascript, angular

Following what is documented here: [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). 
I want to know how is it possible to handle the data inside this `HeroJobAdComponent` class:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { AdComponent }      from './ad.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="job-ad">
      <h4>{{data.headline}}</h4> 

      {{data.body}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class HeroJobAdComponent implements AdComponent {
  @Input() data: any;

}
```

As you can see, `data` is the object holding the data received. I want to be able to define a constructor for my `HeroJobAdComponent` class but if I do, the object `data` is `undefined` inside my constructor. I tried using `ngOnChange` instead which supposedly executes once input is changed from undefined to defined but it also did not execute at all.

Can someone please explain first why is the object undefined even though the data is defined in my main component calling it, and what's the workaround for this issue?

This is the constructor I am using:

```
constructor()
{
    this.values = this.data.values;
    this.spec_name = this.data.spec_name;
}
```

Comment: Any chance to show us your constructor?

Comment: edit done @Aer0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use any operation when you receive data in your component , you can use setter

```
export class HeroJobAdComponent implements AdComponent {

  _data;

  @Input() set data (data: any){
   //operation on data goes here
   this._data=data
  };

  get data() {
   return this._data;
  }

}
```